# Markdown: code snippets in the ordered list

Tags: markdown, octopress, kramdown

I am using Octopress to generate static html-pages with markdown. What I want to do is to embed Pygments-highlighted code blocks inside of an ordered list. 
To include non-highlited code block into ordered list one can do the following:

```
1.  list item 1
    its description
        code block here
2.  list item 2
    its description
        code block
```

And markdown understand it correctly.
But what if I want to include code snippet into ordered list? I am trying this:

`````
1.  list item 1
    its description

    ```
    code block here
    ````

2.  list item 2
    its description

    ```
    code block
    ```
`````

But this way code block is not recognized. Moving backticked code block to the left or to the right doesn't help. If I move it to the left, code block will be highlighted but the next number of a list will be «1», so, it will be a new list.

How can I solve this problem? By the way I am using kramdown, but I didn't get it to work neither with markdown nor with kramdown.

Comment: Can you check the HTML generated, does it contain a `<code class="language-..."`? If so, then it's probably just the CSS that doesn't work inside the list

Comment: It doesn't contain this. But even highlighted code blocks don't contain it. What I have for highlighted block is

Comment: `<div class="bogus-wrapper"><notextile><figure class="code"><div class="highlight">...` and for non-highlighted block is `<pre><code>...`. For the variant I tried I have backticked block in `<pre><code>...`, but in browser it doesn't look like a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kramdown you [have to](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#fenced-code-blocks) use tildes for fenced code blocks (while other markdown implementations support backticks as well):

```
1.  list item 1
    its description

    ~~~
    code block here
    ~~~
```

Comment: Thanks! I _thought_ I was using kramdown, but now I'm not sure what actually Octopress was doing with backticked blocks. Now, if I use 6-spaces indent after `1.` and 8-spaces indentation for all lines before new item, including code blocks, it solves my problem! I have highlighted code blocks within an ordered list. Great, thanks!

Comment: And I'd like to note that it doesn't work in markdown.